# Large number of sockets in TIME_WAIT for Python HTTPServer / Unity C# HTTPClient

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine, networking

I'm trying to get a Unity and Python program to communicate via HTTP. The Unity server sends a HTTP request via HTTPCient, which the Python program handles via HTTPServer. The problem I'm having is that each request seems to send a socket into TIME_WAIT. The communication happens roughly 20 times / second, and eventually there are no more sockets and the program stops functioning. My understanding is this issue is caused by each request using up a new socket without properly closing it, which the Wireshark capture below seems to support (There's only one FIN-ACK at the end, not the 2 I understand TCP to require).

I'm trying to use fewer sockets, or free the sockets sooner so that they could be used again. I've tried a number of approaches to mitigate this issue, including `socket.SO_REUSEADDR`, connection pooling, and keep-alive connections. My suspicion is that I'm not implementing one (or all) of those correctly, but I'm not sure how to confirm that. The code below has my attempts at implementing those below - unfortunately, documentation felt a little sparse on the python side.

```
void Start() {
    HttpClient requester = new HttpClient();
    requester.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    requester.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Keep-Alive", "5000");
    waitForClientResult(requester);
}

private async Task waitForClientResult(HttpClient requester) {
    HttpResponseMessage response = await requester.GetAsync("http://127.0.0.1:5018");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    PythonServerReturnData data = JsonUtility.FromJson<PythonServerReturnData>(responseBody);
    doSomeStuffWithTheData(data);
    waitForClientResult(requester);
}
```

```
agent = UnityAgentHTTP()

class UnityAgentHTTP:
    def __init__(self):
        self.recievedData = None
        self.replyData = "ThisDataUpdatedElsewhere".encode('utf-8')
        self.exit = False

        self.sendThread = threading.Thread(target=self.sendOutput, name='sendThread', daemon = True)
        self.sendThread.start()
    
    def sendOutput(self):
        handler = partial(UnityHTTPServer, self)
        self.httpd = MyHTTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 5018), handler)
        self.httpd.serve_forever()

    def cleanup(self):
        print("cleaning up")
        self.exit = True
        self.httpd.shutdown()
        self.httpd.socket.close()
        self.httpd.server_close()

class MyHTTPServer(HTTPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True  
    def server_bind(self):
        HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        # self.socket.bind(self.server_address)

class UnityHTTPServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    
    protocol_version = 'HTTP/1.1'

    def __init__(self, unityAgentHTTP: UnityAgentHTTP, *args, **kwargs):
        self.unityAgentHTTP = unityAgentHTTP
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def do_HEAD(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "application/json")
        # self.send_header("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
        # self.send_header("keep-alive", "timeout=5, max=30")
        self.send_header("Content-Length", len(self.unityAgentHTTP.replyData) + 20) # TODO horrible hack bc i can't figure out how to count bytes objects properly 
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        self.do_HEAD()
        self.wfile.write(self.unityAgentHTTP.replyData)
        self.close_connection = True
```

[Wireshark capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do7li.png)

Comment: Not sure if this will solve all of your problem, but could it be as simple as not waiting for the async task on the client? I've heard there can be issues if you "fire and forget" async voids without awaiting them, particularly with regards to error handling. Not sure how much of that extends to Tasks, however. You could try something like `waitForClientResult(requester).GetAwaiter().GetResult()` and see if that helps.

Comment: @joshua.software.dev Thanks for the advice! I tried awaiting the call, but it didn't seem to help. And I couldn't get `waitForClientResult(requester).GetAwaiter().GetResult()` working without freezing the program.

Answer (score 0):

One of cases when you can get that behavior is when you are not reusing `HttpClient` instances, and creating a new ones ([here](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) is more info on the topic).

Also you should try to [dispose `response`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/28842) after you finished working with it:

```
private async Task waitForClientResult(HttpClient requester) 
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await requester.GetAsync("http://127.0.0.1:5018");
    try
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        PythonServerReturnData data = JsonUtility.FromJson<PythonServerReturnData>(responseBody);
        doSomeStuffWithTheData(data);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Dispose of HttpResponseMessage to free up system resources and close network connections.
        response.Dispose();
    }
    
    waitForClientResult(requester);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll be sure to call dispose! Unfortunately though, that alone didn't fix the problem. Unless something really funky is happening under the hood I believe HttpClient is already being reused.